# Erlang - Eccentricity with accented characters and string literal

Tags: erlang, diacritics, string-literals

I am trying to implement a function to differentiate between french vowels and consonnants. It should be trivial, let's see what I wrote down :

```
-define(vowels,"aeiouyàâéèêëôù").

is_vowel(Char) -> C = string:to_lower(Char),
                  lists:member(C,?vowels).
```

It's pretty simple, but it behaves incorrectly :

```
2> char:is_vowel($â).
false
```

While the interpreted version works well :

```
3> C = string:to_lower($â), lists:member(C,"aeiouyàâéèêëôù").
true
```

What's going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely thing here is a conflict of encodings. Your vowels list in the compiled code is using different character values for the accented characters. You should be able to see this by defining `acirc() -> $â.` in your compiled code and looking at the number output by calling `char:acirc().` versus `$â.` in the interpreter. I think that the compiler assumes that source files are in ISO-Latin-1 encoding, but the interpreter will consult your locale settings and use that encoding, probably UTF-8 if you're on a modern linux distro. See [Using Unicode in Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html) for more information.

Comment: Seems you are right ; indeed I get an encoding error when implementing acirc(). I've to write something like :

    acirc() -> lists:nth(1,"â").

Which corresponds to Ã in the interpreter. I'll read the document you made mention of. Thanks.